# Linear Fit when Data has Uncertainty

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, linear-regression, weighted-least-squares

I am attempting to find the slope and y-intercept (along with their uncertainty) from a set of data. In this case, I am graphing Gamma Energy (MeV) vs. Peak Centroid (Channel). Here is my data:

Gamma Energy (MeV): 1.17, 1.33, 0.032, 0.662, 0.511, 1.275, 0.088

Peak Centroid (Channel): 622.65, 712, 21, 360.38, 280.64, 676.85, 18.68

Peak Centroid Uncertainty: 0.0342, 0.0347, 2, 0.0155, 0.0231, 0.0288, 0.1346

As can be seen, one Centroid Uncertainty value is significantly higher than the rest, so I cannot use a normal non-weighted least squares fit. I researched this a bit and found that I can use the formula $\left ( X^TWX \right )\hat{\beta }=X^TWy$ to solve for $\hat{\beta}$. Now, I know $y_{i}$ is simply each of my Gamma Energies. I also know $W_{ii}=\frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^2}$ where $\sigma_{i}$ corresponds to each of my Centroid Uncertainties. All other elements in $W$ are $0$. My issue is, I do not know how to contruct $X$. I have looked at various sources, and none of them really made sense to me. What exactly does each element correspond to, and how do I implement that in my case. When I find $\hat{\beta}$, won't this simply correspond to the $m$ and $b$ values in $y=mx+b$? How can I find the uncertainty in $m$ and $b$? Also, in my case, the uncertainties are in the x-values where (I think) the formula I am using assumes them to be in the y-values. Will this affect my results? As an aside, if I had errors in both x and y-values, how would I solve that?

Comment: the $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$ to use in the matrix formula are the respective deviations from the mean: the line passes through $(X_m, Y_m)$.

Comment: and, If the uncertainties are on the $X$, but not on the $Y$, just reverse your line as  $(x-x_m)=q(y-y_m)$

Comment: @GCab I'm sorry, but I don't follow. So you are saying I take the mean of y along with mean of x (with uncertainties figured in), and those are my elements? Because from what I read, y is a vector while X is a nxn+1 matrix. So what are all of the elements in X?

Comment: For what I know, both $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$ are vectors (while $\bf W$ is a diagonal matrix), otherwise the matrix equation you cite would be inconsistent. The vector $\bf X$ would be given by $(x_k-x_m)\; |\,k=1, \cdots, n$. Similar for $\bf Y$. Note that the least square method assumes that the $x$ be "certain", and the 
the $y$ subject to error, following the *same* centered normal distribution.If your situation is the reverse, then you have to reverse the role of $x$ and $y$, and look 
for the regression
$$(x-x_m)=p \cdot (y-y_m)$$.

Comment: To be more helpful please cite the reference you found.

Comment: @GCab I was talking about somebody's lecture notes I looked at (I'm not in that class), but they appear to be wrong. Here is a link to what I am considering: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/352. Here is a link to the same site defining what they mean by $X$ and $y$: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/382. Now, I know I can use this to find $\hat{\beta }=\begin{bmatrix}
b\\m 

\end{bmatrix}$ where $b$ is the y-intercept and $m$ is the slope; however, I still have two questions.

Comment: @GCab 1.) Does the fact that the error is in $X$ rather than $y$ have any effect on this? If so, how exactly will this change things. If possible, I would appreciate the final formula I will be using after the changes have been made. 2.) How can I calculate the error in $b$, $\sigma_{b}$, and $m$, $\sigma_{m}$. I am unsure how to do this at all since I am dealing with the error being in $X$. If you could specifically show me how to accomplish this, I would also be very appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The least square method, in its simplest standard form, assumes that the $x$ be "certain", and the the $y$ subject to error, following the *same* centered normal distribution, i.e. with the same $\sigma$ (homoscedasticity).

You instead want to find  the reverse relation:  then, once you have got $y=mx+b$, you can always reverse it into $x=(1/m)y-b/m$.

Trying to avoid confusion let's follow the standard way, understanding that the $x$ refer to the  error-free variable, while $y$ to that subject to error.
So we are looking for the regression line $y=mx+b$.

2) We assume to have $n$ independent random variables $Y_k$, whose PDF (probability density function) is 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
p\left( {\eta _k } \right) = {1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi \sigma _k ^2 } }}\exp \left( { - {1 \over 2}{{\left( {\eta _k  - \hat m\,x_k  - \hat b} \right)^2 }
 \over {\sigma _k ^2 }}} \right)
} \tag{1}$$
where $\hat y = \hat m\,x_k  + \hat b$ is the supposed "exact" value of $y$, defined by the 
the "exact" values of the parameters $m$ and $b$ indicated with the hat.

3) The probability that we get the $n$-uple of values $(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$, considering the $x$ and $\sigma$ $n$-tuples as fixed, is
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
p\left( {y_1 } \right) \cdots p\left( {y_n } \right)\;dy_1  \cdots dy_n 
} \tag{2}$$
which is maximum when 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
E^2 (m,b) = \sum\limits_k {{{\left( {y_k  - \hat m\,x_k  - \hat b} \right)^2 } \over {\sigma _k ^2 }}}  = \sum\limits_k {\left( {{{y_k  - \hat y_k } \over {\sigma _k }}} \right)^2 } 
} \tag{2}$$
is minimum, which means
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 = {\partial  \over {\partial b}}E^2 (m,b)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \sum\limits_k {{{\left( {y_k  - \hat m\,x_k  - \hat b} \right)} 
\over {\sigma _k ^2 }}}  = 0 \hfill \cr 
  0 = {\partial  \over {\partial m}}E^2 (m,b)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \sum\limits_k {{{\left( {y_k  - \hat m\,x_k  - \hat b} \right)x_k }
 \over {\sigma _k ^2 }}}  = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.
} $$
The first tells us that the estimated value of $b$ (indicated with the tilde)
is equal to this expression involving the weighted average of the $y_k$ and $x_k$
values, with weights $(1/\sigma_k^2)$
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \tilde b = \sum\limits_k {\left( {{{\left( {1/\sigma _k ^2 } \right)} \over {\sum\limits_k {\left( {1/\sigma _k ^2 } \right)} }}} \right)y_k }  - 
\tilde m\sum\limits_k {\left( {{{\left( {1/\sigma _k ^2 } \right)} \over {\sum\limits_k {\left( {1/\sigma _k ^2 } \right)} }}} \right)x_k }  =   \cr 
  &  = \bar y - \tilde m\,\bar x \cr} 
} \tag{3}$$
So we can rewrite the second as 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
0 = \sum\limits_k {{{\left( {y_k  - \hat m\,x_k  - \hat b} \right)x_k } \over {\sigma _k ^2 }}}  = \sum\limits_k {{{\left( {\left( {y_k  - \bar y} \right) - 
\hat m\,\left( {x_k  - \bar x} \right)} \right)\left( {x_k  - \bar x} \right)} \over {\sigma _k ^2 }}} 
} $$
and get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\tilde m  = \sum\limits_k {{{\left( {y_k  - \bar y} \right)\left( {x_k  - \bar x} \right)} \over {\sigma _k ^2 }}} \;\;\mathop /\limits_{} \;\;
\sum\limits_k {{{\left( {x_k  - \bar x} \right)^2 } \over {\sigma _k ^2 }}} 
} \tag{4}$$

4) Passing to the more synthetic vectorial notation, indicating by
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
{\bf Y} = \left( {\matrix{
   {y_1 }  \cr 
   {y_2 }  \cr 
    \vdots   \cr 
   {y_n }  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad {\bf X} = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & {x_1 }  \cr 
   1 & {x_2 }  \cr 
    \vdots  &  \vdots   \cr 
   1 & {x_n }  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad {\bf \beta } = \left( {\matrix{
   b  \cr 
   m  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad {\bf W} = \left( {\matrix{
   {1/\sigma _1 ^2 } & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
   0 & {1/\sigma _2 ^2 } &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \cr 
   0 & 0 &  \cdots  & {1/\sigma _n ^2 }  \cr 
 } } \right)
} $$
we are going to minimize
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
E^2 ({\bf \beta }) = \left( {{\bf W}^{\,{\bf 1/2}} \,\left( {{\bf Y} - {\bf X\beta }} \right)} \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \left( {{\bf W}^{\,{\bf 1/2}} \,\left( {{\bf Y} - {\bf X\beta }} \right)} \right)
} $$
which returns
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
{\bf \tilde \beta } = \left( {{\bf X}^{\,{\bf T}} {\bf WX}} \right)^{ - \,{\bf 1}} {\bf X}^{\,{\bf T}} \,{\bf W}\;{\bf Y}
} \tag{4}$$

Refer also to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Weighted_linear_least_squares).

Applied to your data this gives
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  b=13.27,\;m=522.76 }$$  .

5) Concerning the confidence abour the estimated values of $m$ and $b$,
you can find various considerations in the [already cited article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Weighted_linear_least_squares) as well as
in [this other related one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), together with the necessary cautions as per the statistical soundness and applicability.

However, not pretending to be exhaustive nor totally rigorous, but just to outline the basis of a possible approach,
let's go back to (1) and (2).
We can consider eq. (2) as proportional to the conditional probability of getting the vector $\bf Y$ , given $\bf \beta$
$$
P\left( {{\bf Y}\,\,\left| {\;{\bf \beta }} \right.} \right) \propto p\left( {y_1 } \right) \cdots p\left( {y_n } \right)\;dy_1  \cdots dy_n 
$$
Assuming $P(\bf \beta)$ to be fairly constant, at least within the "admissible" range of values,
then we can put that 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & P\left( {{\bf \beta }\,\,\left| {\,{\bf Y}\;} \right.} \right) \propto p\left( {y_1 } \right) \cdots p\left( {y_n } \right)\;db\,dm \propto   \cr 
  &  \propto \exp \left( { - {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_k {\left( {{{y_k  - \hat m\,x_k  - \hat b} \over {\sigma _k }}} \right)^2 } } \right) = \exp \left( { - {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_k {\left( {{{\,x_k } \over {\sigma _k }}\hat m + {1 \over {\sigma _k }}\hat b - {{y_k } \over {\sigma _k }}} \right)^2 } } \right) \cr} 
} \tag{5}$$
with $x_k, y_k, \sigma_k$ known and fixed.
Let's pay attention to the fact that presuming that the $\sigma_k$ are known, and not to be determined 
by some estimation on the spreadness of the $y_k$, is a crucial point in fixing the statistics of the parameters (Normal instead of Student).

The sum of the quadratic forms in $b,m$ will provide a quadratic form that can be written as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & Q(b,m) = \sum\limits_k {\left( {{1 \over {\sigma _k }}\hat b + {{\,x_k } \over {\sigma _k }}\hat m - {{y_k } \over {\sigma _k }}} \right)^2 }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {T^2 \left( {\hat b - \tilde b} \right)^2  + 2R^2 \left( {\hat b - \tilde b} \right)\left( {\hat m - \tilde m} \right) + U^2 \left( {\hat m - \tilde m} \right)^2  + V^2 } \right) \cr} 
} \tag{6}$$
where it is clear that for $\hat b = \tilde b,\;\hat m = \tilde m$ $Q(b,m)$ attains the minimum value, which is the condition defining
the estimated values.

Taking the first and second derivatives it is possible to express $T,R,U,V$ wrt the known values.
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  T^{\,2}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {1/\sigma _{\,k} } \right)^{\,2} }  \hfill \cr 
  U^{\,2}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {x_{\,k} /\sigma _{\,k} } \right)^{\,2} }  \hfill \cr 
  R^{\,2}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( {x_{\,k} /\sigma _{\,k} ^{\,2} } \right)}  \hfill \cr 
  V^{\,2}  = \sum\limits_k {\left( {{1 \over {\sigma _k }}\tilde b + {{\,x_k } \over {\sigma _k }}\tilde m - {{y_k } \over {\sigma _k }}} \right)^2 }  \hfill \cr}  \right.
} $$

We can translate the above into the equation of a Bivariate Normal Distribution, 
absorbing the term in $V$ into the normalizing factor. 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
{1 \over {2\,\pi \,\sigma _{\,1} \,\sigma _{\,2} \sqrt {1 - \rho ^{\,2} } }}\exp \left( { - {1 \over {2\left( {1 - \rho ^{\,2} } \right)}}\left( {{{\left( {x_{\,1}  - \mu _{\,1} } \right)^{\,2} } \over {\sigma _{\,1} ^{\,2} }} - 2\rho {{\left( {x_{\,1}  - \mu _{\,1} } \right)\left( {x_{\,2}  - \mu _{\,2} } \right)} \over {\sigma _{\,1} \,\sigma _{\,2} }} + {{\left( {x_{\,2}  - \mu _{\,2} } \right)^{\,2} } \over {\sigma _{\,2} ^{\,2} }}} \right)} \right)
} $$
where $\rho$ is the correlation
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\rho  = {\rm corr}\left( {x_{\,1} ,x_{\,2} } \right) = {{V_{12} } \over {\sigma _{\,1} \,\sigma _{\,2} }}
} $$

Finally we reach to
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  \rho  =  - {{R^{\,2} } \over {T\,U}} \approx  - \,0.93396 \hfill \cr 
  \sigma _{\,b}  = {1 \over {T\sqrt {\left( {1 - \rho ^{\,2} } \right)} }} \approx {\rm 0}{\rm .029524} \hfill \cr 
  \sigma _{\,m}  = {1 \over {U\sqrt {\left( {1 - \rho ^{\,2} } \right)} }} \approx {\rm 0}{\rm .033654} \hfill \cr}  \right.
} \tag{7}$$
which result I could counter-check with my old CAS program.

From here you can easily find the ellipse which delimites the parameters
at the required confidence.

Now you can reverse the relation $x->y$.

Comment: I have verified that we have arrived at equivalent formulas. I have accepted your answer as it clearly is the better answer by explaining the process of arriving at the given equations.

Comment: @JavaNewbie: very good ! so we learnt something about the weighted regression together.

Comment: That we did! Thank you very much for all of the time and effort you put into this. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After researching and receiving some direction from G Cab, I have found the following:
$$m=\frac{\sum \frac{x_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2}\cdot \sum \frac{y_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2}-\sum \frac{x_{i}y_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2}\cdot \sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^2}}{\left ( \sum \frac{x_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2} \right )^2-\sum \frac{x_{i}^2}{\sigma_{i}^2}\cdot \sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^2}} \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;
\sigma_{m}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^2}}{\sum \frac{x_{i}^2}{\sigma_{i}^2}\cdot \sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^2}-\left ( \sum \frac{x_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2} \right )^2}}$$

$$b=\frac{\sum \frac{x_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2}\cdot \sum \frac{x_{i}y_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2}-\sum \frac{y_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2}\cdot \sum \frac{x_{i}^2}{\sigma_{i}^2}}{\left ( \sum \frac{x_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2} \right )^2-\sum \frac{x_{i}^2}{\sigma_{i}^2}\cdot \sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^2}}  \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;
\sigma_{b}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum \frac{x_{i}^2}{\sigma_{i}^2}}{\sum \frac{x_{i}^2}{\sigma_{i}^2}\cdot \sum \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^2}-\left ( \sum \frac{x_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^2} \right )^2}}$$
This is for the case of unequal errors. If we have equal errors, this obviously reduces to its normal form. Please note that this assumes the error is in the y-values (dependent variable) while the x-values are error-free (dependent variable). In order to use this in my application, I had to fit the equation $x=qy+p$ where I used the equations above (switching $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$ in the formulas). In this case, $p$ corresponds to $m$ and $q$ corresponds to $b$. After this, we rearrange the fit in the way we want it: $y=\frac{1}{q}x-\frac{p}{q}$. Thus, we arrive at

$$m=\frac{1}{q} \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \sigma_{m}=\sqrt{\sigma_{q}^2\left ( \frac{\partial m}{\partial q} \right )^2}=\frac{\sigma_{q}}{q}$$

$$b=-\frac{p}{q} \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \sigma_{b}=\sqrt{\sigma_{q}^2\left ( \frac{\partial b}{\partial q} \right )^2+\sigma_{p}^2\left ( \frac{\partial b}{\partial p} \right )^2}=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{p}^2}{q^2}+\frac{\sigma_{q}^2\cdot p^2}{q^4}}
$$

Comment: I posted my new answer, and then so your auto-reply: I did not check  with mine.